# What is the Characater limit of Google Chat message

Tags: google-chat

Is there any way to increase the character limit of google chat API message
I am looking for a way to increase the *character limit* of the message.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*The limit of a Google Chat message is 4096 Characters.*

#### Proof:

[image]

#### Increasing the Character limit:

This is not possible. It is a hard limit set out by Google and there is no method set out to increase it.

#### Workarounds:

- Send two messages
- Take a screenshot of your larger text and send it as an image
- Send a link to a webpage which contains the full text
- Send the larger text using Gmail instead of Chat